# Start concurrent batches with filename mask and wait for them to finish

Tags: batch-file, concurrency, wait

I'm trying to start a fixed number of concurrent batch processes that have similar filenames, all in the same directory:

```
TestMe1.bat
TestMe2.bat
TestMe3.bat
```

All batches should start at the same time, and all should complete before the batch continues, e.g. a master.bat:

```
echo Starting batches

(
start "task1" cmd /C "TestMe1.bat"
start "task2" cmd /C "TestMe2.bat"
start "task3" cmd /C "TestMe3.bat"
) | pause

echo All batches have stopped and we can safely continue
```

I'm trying to find a way to start all batches in the directory that match TestMe*.bat, so that  I don't have to craft a new master.bat file each time.  Something like this, but, you know, working:

```
echo Starting batches

(
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /a-d TestMe*.bat') do start "task" cmd /C "%%x"
) | pause

echo All batches have stopped and we can safely continue
```

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49051876/1848410) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20924102/1848410) for getting me this far.

Advice and ideas gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to understand how this special method of using pipe with the `pause` command works and why it can be used for waiting for multiple parallel processes.

Taking your first working code sample as the starting point

```
(
start "task1" cmd /C "TestMe1.bat"
start "task2" cmd /C "TestMe2.bat"
start "task3" cmd /C "TestMe3.bat"
) | pause
```

It works because each new instance of CMD which is invoked by the `start` command will be started in a new console with its `stdout` and `stderr` redirected to to that new console, so the outputs of the child CMDs will not be redirected to the pipe and so will not be consumed by the `pause` command which is waiting for input from the pipe.

BUT,
Still each of the processes have inherited the pipe handle, so the handle to the pipe will remain open as long as the child processes are alive.

As a consequence the `pause` command in the right side of the pipe will remain active, waiting for input from the left side of the pipe until it receives input from the pipe(which will never happen) or all child processes have terminated and closed the handle to the pipe.

So the main CMD instance which is executing your master batch file, is actually waiting for the `pause` command (right side of the pipe) to terminate which in turn is waiting for child processes (potential pipe writers) to terminate.

Now it becomes clear why your second attempted code involving the `FOR` loop is not working.

```
(
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /a-d TestMe*.bat') do start "task" cmd /C "%%x"
) | pause
```

The `FOR` command inside the pipe is executed by the child CMD in command line mode, In this mode the **command echoing** in on by default, so every command inside the `FOR` body will be echoed to standard output(the pipe) before execution, which in turn feeds the `pause` command and terminate its process before even the first child process is created, Therefor the batch file execution continues without ever waiting for the child processes to finish.

This can be easily resolved by putting the `@` after `do` will turn the command echoing off inside the `FOR` body.

```
(
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /a-d TestMe*.bat') do @start "task" cmd /C "%%x"
) | pause>nul
```

You may also want to hide the output of `pause` command by redirecting it to `nul`

Comment: Great explanation, and a really simple fix too - thanks @sst

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that's very interesting. I didn't really understand how it's supposed to work but now I do. So as far as I can tell, the trick is that `( ..... ) | command` spawns processes with `STDOUT` redirected into  `STDIN` pipe of the `command`. And although `start` directives all exit immidiately and cannot connect the pipe to another console, processes spawned that way still inherit its HANDLE. And until *all* of the HANDLEs to the input side of the pipe are closed the pipe cannot signal an EOF.

Comment: @JackWhite, Yes that is correct, Theoretically even the processes that are spawned by `start` which creates a new console can write to the pipe if they could somehow be informed of the inherited pipe handle value and and were specifically designed to do so. For instance if you use `start /b` to create any process, its `stdout` will be set to the pipe handle so it automatically writes to the pipe. The pipe handle will be inherited and is usable by child processes regardless of their `stdout` being redirected or not.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It seems I missed the point of this question. Despite that, I think I'll leave this here anyway for other people to find. Feel free to downvote though.

---

Here are other suggestions on waiting for subordinate processes to complete.

Your main process should periodically check if every subordinate processes is done. There is a multitude of ways of doing that. I'll name a few:

Before that, please insert a delay between checks to not consume all CPU in a tight loop like this:

```
timeout /t 1 /nobreak
```

#### Marker files

Make subordinate processes create or delete a file when they are about to finish

You can create files like this:

```
echo ANYTHING>FILENAME
```

Main script should periodically check if those files exist like this:

```
if exist FILENAME goto IT_EXISTS
```

When all/none of the files exist your task is complete.

To prevent clutter, create files in a `%random%` folder inside `%temp%` directory and pass its name to subordinates via arguments `%1`, `%2` ...

#### Check process existance by window title

Run `tasklist` and parse its output to determine if your subordinate programs still run.

Probably the easiest way is to use window name to filter out "your" processes.

Start them like this:

```
start "WINDOW_TITLE" "BATCH_FILE" ARGUMENTS
```

then search for them like this:

```
TASKLIST /fi "Windowtitle eq WINDOW_TITLE" | find ".exe"
if "%errorlevel%" == "0" goto PROCESS_EXISTS
```

if none are found your task is finished.

Further information can be found at: [A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266509/check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not), [B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script), [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969595/exit-status-of-tasklist-in-batch-file)

#### Check process existance by PID

Instead of window title you can use processes' PID.

To obtain it run your process with `WMIC` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192852/how-to-get-the-output-of-wmic-process-call-create)

#### External programs

You can download or write an external program to facilitate inter-process communication. Examples include:

- TCP server and clients with `netcat`
- Use `mkfifo` from GnuWin32 coreutils to create a named pipe and use it
- Windows semaphores and events via custom C/C#/AutoIT program
- Utilities such as `NirCmd` and `PsExec` may simplify PID checking procedure

....and more

If none of solutions work for you please edit the question to narrow down your query.

Comment: These are all good ideas, but the event-driven model works better for my purposes - thanks for your answer nonetheless